# Translate raw complex SQL query into Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Can anyone help me translate this into Eloquent?

```
select * from resources 
left join links 
    on links.resource_id = resources.id 
        and (links.ud_id IS NULL OR links.ud_id = '7') 
where resources.user_id = '1' 
    and resources.subject_id = '4'
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
DB::table('resources')
  ->leftJoin('links', function($join) {
    $join->on('links.resource_id', '=', 'resources.id');
    $join->where(function($query) {
      $query->whereNull('links.ud_id');
      $query->orWhere('links.ud_id', '=', 7);
    });
  })
  ->where('user_id', 1)
  ->where('subject_id', 4)
  ->get();
```

Comment: Perfect. Just a little detail that has been straitforward sorted out. Instead of orWhere('links.ud_id', 7) I have had to change it to orWhere('links.ud_id', '=', 7). I thought both were equivalent but apparently not in this case. Brilliant, Jedrzej!